# Scale Flex Grid to Container?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, responsiveness

I'm trying to create a gallery of sorts. There will be a variable amount of items in this; I need it to fit the browser viewport, so the items in the gallery should be able to flexibly scale. It feels like it should be a simple endeavour?

Right now, my DOM looks like this:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

With accompanying CSS:

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

When I get to a certain number of children, they just overflow the parent. I'd like them to scale their height/width so that they fit the parent. When I get to just a few (1-3) children, I'd like them to scale to fit it, too. Surely the `flex: 1 1 auto` would suffice?

Is CSS grid the wrong direction? Would I be better off with Grid?

Comment: Not sure what you are seeing, but I can't replicate your issue. Maybe post an image of what you are seeing or what you are wanting to see?

https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/42d43f8d56a64a050954c080484ef039

Comment: Hey, it was late... I've put together a pen - hopefully this illustrates the issue better? I'd like to keep the gallery here in the viewport https://codepen.io/hjfitz/pen/LYxJWee

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set width with width? e.g. **width:33.33%** Maybe this is an interesting effect?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work in the way I wanted it to, with grid. In my application, depending on the amount of items in the gallery, I'll modify the number of grid columns with JavaScript; I've omitted this in the pen.

Using grid, I've used `grid-template-columns: repeat($num, 1fr);`. I've also made use of `grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, 100px);` to ensure that rows fit the screen.

Here's a pen that explains it better: https://codepen.io/hjfitz/pen/LYxJWQe